# Python how to pass command line argument to function properly

Tags: python

I am newbie to Python and I have a code below that I want to take command line argument and pass argument value to functions as packet filter, but it is not working

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse
from scapy import all
from scapy.layers import all
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, ICMP, UDP
from scapy.packet import ls, Raw
from scapy.sendrecv import sniff, send
from scapy.all import *
#UDPPORT = 8472
#SRCPORT = 55555
#DSTHOST= "172.18.0.1"
#INNERIP = "10.1.5.1"
VNI = 2
PAYLOAD='zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'


def udp_monitor_callback(pkt):
    inLayer3 = pkt.payload.payload.payload.payload.payload

    if(pkt.haslayer(IP) and inLayer3.dst == INNERIP):
        print("incoming IP packet matches",  INNERIP)
        outLayer3 = pkt.payload
        udpLayer = pkt.payload.payload
        vxlanLayer = pkt.payload.payload.payload
        inLayer2 = pkt.payload.payload.payload.payload
        inLayer4 = pkt.payload.payload.payload.payload.payload.payload

        outerIP=IP(src=outLayer3.dst, dst=outLayer3.src)

        udpinfo=UDP(sport=SRCPORT, dport=UDPPORT)

        vxlan=VXLAN(flags=vxlanLayer.flags, vni=VNI)

        innerETH=Ether(dst=inLayer2.src, src=inLayer2.dst, type=0x800)

        innerIP=IP(src=inLayer3.dst,dst=inLayer3.src)

        innerICMP=ICMP(type=0, code=0, id=inLayer4.id, seq=inLayer4.seq)

        send(outerIP/udpinfo/vxlan/innerETH/innerIP/innerICMP/PAYLOAD)

    if(pkt.haslayer(ARP)):
        print("incoming ARP packet")

def dispatcher_callback(pkt):
    print ('Destination port "', UDPPORT)
    print ('Outer destination IP "', DSTHOST)
    if(pkt.haslayer(UDP) and (pkt[UDP].dport == UDPPORT) and (pkt[IP].dst == DSTHOST)):
        print("incoming VXLAN packet")
        udp_monitor_callback(pkt)
    else:
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    
    global UDPPORT
    global DSTHOST

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--Dport")
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--OuterIP")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.Dport:
        print("Displaying Dport as: % s" % args.Dport)
        UDPPORT=args.Dport

    if args.OuterIP:
        print("Displaying Destination IP as: % s" % args.OuterIP)
        DSTHOST=args.OuterIP
    

    print("Scapy vxlan responder")
    scapy.all.conf.iface = "br-22b28ede79c2"
    sniff(filter=("port %s") % (UDPPORT), prn=dispatcher_callback)
```

for example I ran the script

```
# ./vxlan-test.py -o 172.18.0.1 -d 8472
Displaying Dport as: 8472
Displaying Destination IP as: 172.18.0.1
Scapy vxlan responder
```

and start sending packet to test, the script output

```
root@cilium-worker:/home/vincent# ./vxlan-test.py -o 172.18.0.1 -d 8472
Displaying Dport as: 8472
Displaying Destination IP as: 172.18.0.1
Scapy vxlan responder
Destination port " 8472
Outer destination IP " 172.18.0.1
Destination port " 8472
Outer destination IP " 172.18.0.1
Destination port " 8472
Outer destination IP " 172.18.0.1
Destination port " 8472
Outer destination IP " 172.18.0.1
```

you can see in `dispatcher_callback(pkt)` it prints the output, but it appears `if(pkt.haslayer(UDP) and (pkt[UDP].dport == UDPPORT) and (pkt[IP].dst == DSTHOST)):` condition does not match since no `print("incoming VXLAN packet")` output

If I do not use command line argument and hard code the values like the beginning of the script commented out with `#`, the script works fine.

Comment: What type is `pkt[IP].dport`? `UDPPORT` is a `str`, so it would cause the comparison to fail if the types don't match

Comment: You can prove @C.Nivs has the right idea if you put your hardcoded values for `UDPPORT` and `SRCPORT` in quotes and try again.

Comment: Yes I can prove @C.Nivs has the right idea, same problem with hardcoded value for `UDPPORT` with quote, so how can I pass the correct type from command line?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the input, here is my working script

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse
from scapy import all
from scapy.layers import all
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, ICMP, UDP
from scapy.packet import ls, Raw
from scapy.sendrecv import sniff, send
from scapy.all import *
PAYLOAD='zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'


def udp_monitor_callback(pkt):
    inLayer3 = pkt.payload.payload.payload.payload.payload

    if(pkt.haslayer(IP) and inLayer3.dst == INNERIP):
        print("incoming IP packet matches",  INNERIP)
        outLayer3 = pkt.payload
        udpLayer = pkt.payload.payload
        vxlanLayer = pkt.payload.payload.payload
        inLayer2 = pkt.payload.payload.payload.payload
        inLayer4 = pkt.payload.payload.payload.payload.payload.payload

        outerIP=IP(src=outLayer3.dst, dst=outLayer3.src)

        udpinfo=UDP(sport=SRCPORT, dport=UDPPORT)

        vxlan=VXLAN(flags=vxlanLayer.flags, vni=VNI)

        innerETH=Ether(dst=inLayer2.src, src=inLayer2.dst, type=0x800)

        innerIP=IP(src=inLayer3.dst,dst=inLayer3.src)

        innerICMP=ICMP(type=0, code=0, id=inLayer4.id, seq=inLayer4.seq)

        send(outerIP/udpinfo/vxlan/innerETH/innerIP/innerICMP/PAYLOAD)

    if(pkt.haslayer(ARP)):
        print("incoming ARP packet")

def dispatcher_callback(pkt):
    if(pkt.haslayer(UDP) and (pkt[UDP].dport == UDPPORT) and (pkt[IP].dst == DSTHOST)):
        print("incoming VXLAN packet")
        udp_monitor_callback(pkt)
    else:
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    global UDPPORT
    global SRCPORT
    global DSTHOST
    global INNERIP
    global VNI
    global BRIDGE

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--dport", action="store", dest="udpport", type=int, help="VXLAN UDP port")
    parser.add_argument("--sport", action="store", dest="srcport", type=int, help="UDP source port")
    parser.add_argument("--vni", action="store", dest="vxlanvni", type=int, help="VXLAN VNI value")
    parser.add_argument("--outerip", action="store", dest="dsthost", help="Outer dst IP")
    parser.add_argument("--innerip", action="store", dest="innerhost", help="Inner dst IP")
    parser.add_argument("--bridge", action="store", dest="bridge", help="Bridge interface to sniff")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.udpport:
        print("Destination port: % d" % args.udpport)
        UDPPORT=args.udpport

    if args.srcport:
        print("Source port: % d" % args.srcport)
        SRCPORT=args.srcport

    if args.vxlanvni:
        print("VXLAN VNI: % d" % args.vxlanvni)
        VNI=args.vxlanvni

    if args.dsthost:
        print("Destination IP: % s" % args.dsthost)
        DSTHOST=args.dsthost

    if args.innerhost:
        print("Inner destination IP as: % s" % args.innerhost)
        INNERIP=args.innerhost

    if args.bridge:
        print("Bridge interface: % s" % args.bridge)
        BRIDGE=args.bridge


    print("Scapy vxlan responder")
    scapy.all.conf.iface = BRIDGE
    sniff(filter=("port %s") % (UDPPORT), prn=dispatcher_callback)
```